# Use a `TableQuery[A]` in a plain sql slick query

Tags: scala, slick

Is it possible to use a defined `TableQuery[Foo]` in a slick plain sql query ala

```
sql"SELECT * FROM foo".as[Foo]
```

without also manually providing an implicit `GetResult[Foo]`? Must I define both if I want to query `Foo`s using both lifted embedding and plain sql? Is there a way to derive a `GetResult[Foo]` from a `TableQuery[Foo]`?